# Custom error messages on doctrine validations 2

Tags: php, doctrine

Taken from: [Custom error messages on doctrine validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234301/custom-error-messages-on-doctrine-validations)

I am repeating the above question, although it had a very good answer from [Pascal MARTIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138475/pascal-martin), 10 years ago.
I want to know if Doctrine, now, have the capacity to customise the message in the entity's metadata, something like:

```php
class App 
{   

   /**
     * @Column( type="text", 
     *          nullable=false, 
     *          message="This field can't be null, because is very important.")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, because it is a database constraint and then it is your database that raise an exception that is send back to you by Doctrine.

Still you can do an [`assertion`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html) to validate it is not `null`

```
class App 
{   

    /**
     * @Column( 
     *     type="text", 
     *      nullable=false, 
     * )
     * @Assert\NotNull(
     *     message="This field can't be null, because is very important."
     * ) 
     */
    protected $name;
}
```